# how to validate an ognl expression

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

in struts 2 I want to save an ognl expression in my db and use it later to validate something.
There is a way to check if that expression is formally correct?

Exist a library or a regex for that?

Comment: What do you mean by *ognl expression to validate something*?

Comment: You mean validate the syntax of OGNL expression? So just run it and see if it executes correctly.

Comment: yes sorry, I mean validate the syntax of OGNL expression.

Comment: Be wary of allowing arbitrary OGNL expressions to run in your application. How are you executing the OGNL?

Comment: Withh `debugInterceptor` in place you can add `?debug=console` to url and get access to OGNL console (only in `devMode`)

Comment: I need to save the ognl expression string and then use it later. But I have to check if the syntax is correct.